# Why TypeScript can't destruct without declaration?

Tags: typescript

This works

```
let {a, b} = { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

But this isn't

```
let a: number, b: number
{a, b} = { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

That's strange. Is it the way it is supposed to be or do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

In first exemple, you already declared type by value, the compilation already know that variables is numbers. You only can use destructuring assignment syntax in object ({} = {}) with declaration in typescript, in ES6 you can without declaration.

```
// let {a, b} = { a: 1, b: 2 } 
var _a = { a: 1, b: 2 }, a = _a.a, b = _a.b;


//let a: number, b: number;
//{a, b} = { a: 1, b: 2 } <-- Print error in compilation
{
    a, b;
}
{
    a: 1, b;
    2;
}


//let a: number, b: number;
//[a, b] = [1,2]
_b = [1, 2], a = _b[0], b = _b[1];
var _b;
```

This is the result of compilation in two examples.